# In object-oriented programming, is the object part of the method call?

Tags: java, definitions

For example, imagine I have an object defined like so:

```
public class Example {
    public void doSomething() {
        // does something
    }
}
```

If I wanted to call `doSomething`, I'd need an instance of `Example`:

```
Example foo = new Example();
foo.doSomething();  // doSomething is executed
```

My question is, what part of the line `foo.doSomething();` is officially considered the *method call*?

Is it just the `doSomething()` part or is it the entire statement including the object (`foo.doSomething()`)?

Comment: `.doSomething()` is meaningless without is owning instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, the whole `target.method()` is considered part of the method invocation:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html#20448

This means that if you have code like this:

```
foo.bar().baz()
```

...then the whole expression is the method invocation of `baz()`, and the target of that method invocation is itself another method invocation.

Answer (score 1):

`doSomething` is a member of the Example class.
`foo` is an instance of the Example class.

Comment: pardon me, but how does it answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

doSomething() is the method call, foo is the instance of Example that the method is being called on/from.

The dot operator de-references the object foo, and then accesses foo's base object.  That object in this case is Example.  It then accesses Example's method doSomething() in which case something is done.  In this scenario foo is a reference to the object instantiated from the class Example.  The dot operator de-references foo, and doSomething() accesses the de-referenced base class in order to call the method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the is a governing body controlling the OOP terminology, but as fat as i'm concerned methods in OOP can't be independent of classes. You have two choices, you call an instance method or a class (static) method. Ether way, you need to give the name of the entity (class or object) you call the method of and the method name. So foo.doSometghing()  is the method call.

Answer (score 0):

In short, just the `doSomething()`.  For an *instance method* (such as your `doSomething()` method), we would say that you *called the method on the object*.  Every instance method has an extra argument, called `this`, which represents the object that you called the method on, and the language passes it to the method automatically for you.

`doSomething()` is the method, and `foo` is the instance that you called the method on.  `foo` will be implicitly passed as the `this` parameter.